# Obtaining services in RouteInitializer

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to restrict a page in my Angular Dart app to users who are logged in. I know that I can store and retrieve the current user via windows.session but I am trying to figure out the Angular Dart way of getting *auth.isLoggedIn* to the RouteInitializer as it's not injected to the router as it would be with a component. Any help is appreciated.

```dart
void myRouteInitializer(Router router, RouteViewFactory views) {
  views.configure({
      'foo': ngRoute(
          path: '/foo/bar',
          viewHtml: '<baz></baz>',
          preEnter: (RoutePreEnterEvent e) {
            // how to obtain auth?
            e.allowEnter(new Future.value(auth.isLoggedIn));
          })
  });
}
```